# ord(g) = n $\cdot$ n' with gcd(n,n')=1 show that exist two elements such that g=h $\cdot$ h'=h' $\cdot$ h with ord(h)=n and ord(h')= n

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

I was asked the following question and having an hard time to finish the proof:

Let $G$ be a group and let $g \in G$ with ord(g)=n $\cdot$'n and gcd(n,n')=1. Show that exist $h,h'\in G$ such that ord(h)=n , ord(h')=n' and g=h $\cdot$ h'= h'$\cdot$ h.

My attempt: By Chinese remainder theorem we get that $\Bbb Z_{n \cdot n'} \cong \Bbb Z_n \times \Bbb Z_{n'}$ lets define an isomorphism $\psi : \Bbb Z_n \times \Bbb Z_{n'} \to \lt g \gt$ as follows:

$\psi$(i,j):= $h^i \cdot h'^j$ where $i \in \Bbb Z_n$ and $j\in \Bbb Z_{n'}$ such that g=h $\cdot$ h'=h' $\cdot$ h (this works since a cyclic group is abiliean) and $h,h'\in \lt g \gt$.

It wasn't that hard to prove that $\psi$ is an isomorphism the result is that $|<g>| = |\Bbb Z_n \times \Bbb Z_{n'}| = |\Bbb Z_n| \cdot |\Bbb Z_{n'}|$ = n $\cdot$ n'.

I am having an hard time to connect the fact that h' $\cdot$ h=g then $|<g>|=|<h \cdot h '>|$ and that ord(h) must be n and ord(h') must be h'... any help would be apprecited!

Comment: What is the * notation, it is more confusing than just using the \cdot or nothing

Comment: changed my bad @julio_es_sui_glace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\operatorname{ord}(g)= nm$ with $\gcd (n,m)= 1$. Hence you have an isomorphism
$$\begin{align}
\phi: \langle g \rangle &\to \mathbb{Z}/nm\mathbb{Z} \\
g &\mapsto \bar{1}
\end{align}$$
And a second one given by chinese remainder theorem
$$\psi: \mathbb{Z}/nm\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} $$
This gives you an isomorphism $\psi \circ \phi: \langle g \rangle \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} $ then we just set $h = (\psi \circ \phi)^{-1} (\bar{1},\bar{0})$ and $h’ = (\psi \circ \phi)^{-1} (\bar{0},\bar{1}) $

You have thus $\operatorname{ord}(h) = \operatorname{ord} (\bar{1},\bar{0}) = n$ and $\operatorname{ord}(h’) = \operatorname{ord}(\bar{0},\bar{1}) = m$.

Then we now that $\psi(\bar{1}) = (\bar{1}, \bar{1} ) = (\bar{1},\bar{0}) + (\bar{0},\bar{1})$ this is part of chinese remainder thm. We thus get
$$\psi \circ \phi(g) = \psi(\bar{1}) = (\bar{1},\bar{0}) + (\bar{0},\bar{1})  = \psi \circ \phi(h) + \psi \circ \phi(h’) = \psi \circ \phi (hh’) $$
Thus $hh’ = g$.

In conclusion you had all the right ideas, which is cool! You just needed to use isomorphism instead of cardinals.

Comment: I understand, tyvm!

Comment: actually I am wondering now how can I claim that g=h' $\cdot$ h based what u did? And just to be sure ord(1,0) = ord($Z_n$) is that what u meant?

Comment: Of course let me add it

Comment: You can compute by hand what ord(1,0) is, beware it is the additive law!

Comment: Got it, tyvm dude!